# Is there a simple way to add newlines into individual items in a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, newline

I am making a quiz project for school using Python, and as a part of it **I have to have the questions and answers stored in an external file**. Currently, the questions and their answers are on the same line in the text document they are being received from, e.g.;

1. What does CPU stand for?\na) Central Programming Unit\nb) Central Processing Unit\nc) Cooling Process Unit\nd) Computer Processing Unit

However, when it is printed, the `\n` is not functioning and looks exactly as I have formatted it above. Is there a simple way to make the answers go on separate lines **whilst keeping the question and all four answers** in the same list item? The entire functionality of the project is fine, this visual bug is the only issue.

If it helps, here is a somewhat simplified part of the code in question:

```
questions_answers = open("q&a.txt", "r")

class Question:
    def __init__(self, question, answer):
        self.question = question
        self.answer = answer


line_of_questions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for position, line in enumerate(questions_answers):
    if position in line_of_questions:
        question_prompts.append(line)

questions = [
    Question(question_prompts[0], "b"),
    Question(question_prompts[1], "a"),
    Question(question_prompts[2], "c"),
    Question(question_prompts[3], "a"),
    Question(question_prompts[4], "d")
]

def Start_Quiz(questions):
    score = 0
    for question in questions:
        answer = input(question.question)
        if answer == question.answer:
            score += 1


Start_Quiz(questions)
```

Comment: Where is the code that prints?

Comment: answer = input(question.question)

Comment: I'm aware, the point of it being in the parenthesis after the input function is so that it is displayed to the user followed by allowing them to input. It works exactly the same as say, input("Please enter your name")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR:

Let's say `question` is the string you want to print. You can do the following to make it shown in your desired way:

```
import codecs
unescaped_question = codecs.escape_decode(bytes(question, "utf-8"))[0].decode("utf-8")
print(unescaped_question)
```

Now, let me explain more...

Consider a normal string object in python `str("Question\nAnswer")`. If you print it, either to terminal or a file, it will naturally formatted into:

```
Question
Answer
```

You have to go "extra length" to  escape the string by making it `str("Question\\nAnswer")` to make it appear as

```
 Question\nAnswer
```

in a text file. This is why when you read it back from a file and print it again, you will not get "Question" and "Answer" separated.

Intuitively it makes perfect sense, because if you read a line from a file and immediately print it back, no change ought to happen. Unfortunately, it also means your pre-printf-formatted text file needs further processing...

Comment: Thank you for this, where in my code would I put it? Do I need to make any modifications to work with my variable names? I'm still new to Python as you can probably tell, so thank you for helping

Comment: I assume you are reading line from a file object, say `f`, by using `question = f.readline()`. Then you just need to:
`unescaped_question = codecs.escape_decode(bytes(question, "utf-8"))[0].decode("utf-8")
print(unescaped_question)`
Also, add the `import codecs" top of your file

Comment: I'm sorry to be a hassle but I still don't understand, the line is being displayed through use of the answer = input(question.question) line, I can't get it to work even when I try making a new script more similar to your assumptions

Comment: Hint:
I am using `print()` to print. And you are using `input()` to print. It doesn't matter what is used to print, but what is printed is the key. In my example, the printed content is called `unescaped_question`. To generate the content, a original read from file called `question` is needed. In your case, `question`'s equivalence is `question.question`

Comment: I went to bed after trying to get it to work for about an hour last night, and I just woke up this morning and managed to get it working within minutes, thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you should print the lines before asking for input

```
for question in questions:
    for line in question.question.split('\\n'):
        print(line)
    answer = input()
```

Otherwise, rather than splitting, I suggest storing your data in a better file format like JSON, for example, and then you can parse that and loop over the options list

```
{ 
  "questions": [{
    "prompt": "What is a CPU",
    "options": [
      "A) Central ...",
      "B) Cooling ..."
    ],
    "answer": "A"
  }]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, I've attempted to get this to work but I just get an error; AttributeError: 'Question' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Sorry, forgot it was a list of objects

Comment: I have no idea how to use JSON but I will try and figure it out, thank you